# How do you access scope values (in your tests) on an Angular controller written in TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, jasmine, karma-jasmine

If you write your angular controller in TypeScript in a way so that the controller accepts the `$scope` as input parameter:

```
class TestCtrl {

    constructor($scope:ng.IScopeService) {
        $scope.myData = "Information";
    }
}
```

you can easily verify properties on the scope in the following way from your tests:

```
beforeEach(function() {
    $controller("TestCtrl", { $scope: $scope });
});

it("Should have some data set upon creation", function() {
    expect($scope.myData).not.toBeUndefined(); // this is perfectly fine, and we can assert the data.
});
```

You can also create your controller in this way, *not* providing the $scope in the constructor:

```
interface ITestScope {
    myData: string;
}

class TestCtrl implements ITestScope {
    myData: string; // this will be available on the scope as well.

    constructor() {
         this.myData = "Information";   
    }
}
```

Now from my tests, how would I access this scope and verify the data, when I dont have access to `$scope` anymore?

Comment: invalid syntax - It should be `this.myData = "Information"; `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not injecting a scope in your controller (`constructor($scope:ng.IScopeService) {`) so you don't need to pass it in the locals of `$controller`. And seems like you are using `controller as` syntax (as you are assigning properties on the controller instance) so just use the controller instance returned by the `$controller` service.

i.e

```
var ctrl;
beforeEach(function() {
   ctrl = $controller("MyCtrl", {}); //No locals and assign result to a variable
});

it("Should have some data set upon creation", function() {
    expect(ctrl.myData).not.toBeUndefined(); // Set your expectation on controller instance
   //expect(ctrl.myData).toBeDefined() //This is just as same...
});
```

Comment: I tried this, but all I got was `undefined` for the `myData` property.

Comment: @JimAho Which means that you are not assigning it properly or your test is incorrect. You would need to show more code. And it is undefined with the pasted code (in your question) because you are really not assigning anything to `myData: string[];` Just for testing in your code do `myData: string[] = ["AAA", "BBB"];` and check it out. Also if you are using controllerAs then `$scope.controllerAliasThatYouAreUsing` will be the controller instance as well.

Comment: I am indeed using the controllerAs syntax.

Comment: @JimAho How is `MyCtrl` related to `TestCtrl `? You have a lot of things (that may be relevant) not provided in your question. Are you even registering the controller properly and using the correct controller?

Comment: They were not related at all. I've updated the question with more code. The registration and all works fine, it's just that i cannot access the property on the controller returned.

Comment: @JimAho If you are doing exact same thing as what you are doing in your question it will work as per my answer. If not, please replicate it in a demo? It seems like code in your question is hypothetical (looking at the typoes and mistakes in the question edit) and you are doing something else. For ex if you are assigning from an ajax call or async operation it may need you to invoke a digest cycle...

Comment: Yes you were right, it did indeed work. The problem I had was that I was using the `$q` service, and I did not call `$apply` explicitly in my tests before verifying the values, so it was still `undefined`.